# Joomla 3.3 specific menu item nofollow

Tags: php, joomla, seo

I want to add rel="nofollow" to certain menu items in Joomla menu. I do not want to change Joomla core files. What I want is to put in menu options nofollow for "Link Type" tab "Link Title Attribute" and then in menu overrides to check with help of php if the link has title tag and nofollow attribute in it replace it with rel="nofollow".
I managed to do this with jquery, but I am afraid for some search engines not to consider jquery, so I would like to do this server side.
Is there a way to get this?
Thanks

Comment: This question is also asked on the joomla-OS here: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/joomla-3-3-specific-menu-item-nofollow .  Please dont ask your question on more than one forum. (see meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu  )

Answer (score 2):

If you need this only for a single (or a few) meny types, you can override the xml-file for the menu type by copying f.eks. /components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.xml to your template /templates/yourtemplate/html/com_content/article/default.xml (you possibly have to copy default.php as well?). Then add in a new field:

```
<field name="nofollow" type="radio" default="0" label="Should robots follow?"
description="">
    <option value="0">Follow</option>
    <option value="1">No follow</option>
</field>
```

Now override the menu module by copying /modules/mod_menu/tmpl/default_component.php to /templates/yourtemplate/html/mod_menu/ and, and there check if nofollow is true (you should be able to retrieve this value like suggested below):

```
if($item->params->get('nofollow', 0)) { 
// add rel="nofollow" in default_component.php 
// on lines 31 to 39, where the links are defined
}
```

Comment: Hello This works for me in a menu normal, but not in a item that is external link.if you dont mind help me and say in what component I have to insert. Thank you

Comment: Not sure this can be done on the component-level, but if you have a limited and fairly static number of menu items you want to restrict, you can hardcode it. Try to override the file /modules/mod_menu/tmpl/default_url.php (copy it to /templates/yourtemplate/html/mod_menu/default_url.php ). Now you can just add rel="nofollow" on certain menu items, based on the Itemid, like: 
$rel='';
if(in_array($item->id, array(101, 102, nnn ...))) {$rel='rel="nofollow"'; }
...then define the <a> - elements like <a <?php echo $rel; ?> ...>...</a>

Comment: Thank you works perfect. if(in_array($item->id, array(218))) { 
 $no_sigas='rel="nofollow"';

}